# Powershell: Test path by only knowing one part of the actual filename

Tags: powershell, administrator

```
Test-Path C:\Temptest\keeran* -PathType Leaf
```

The command will give a true, coz I have got a file that begins with the name keeran.

How can I do the same, but I have put the path into a variable. How can I use the * 
The following command doesn't work

```
$ppath =  C:\Temptest
$file = keeran
## Doesn't work
Test-Path -Path "$ppath\$file*"
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it on my computer and it worked, the only thing I did was adding the quotes.
This code worked for me:

```
$ppath =  "C:\Temptest"
$file = "keeran"
## Doesn't work
Test-Path -Path "$ppath\$file*"
```

What error did you get?